# Casting char** to char* - Does it change what it points to?

Tags: c, casting, point

If I have a pointer to an array of char*s, in other words, a char** named p1, what would I get if I do (char*)p1? I’m guessing there would be some loss of precision. What information would I lose, and what would p1 now be pointing to? Thanks!

Comment: An array of `char *` is not a `char **`. Arrays are not pointers.

Comment: @DavidBowling That's correct. Thank you for pointing that out. I edited it.

Comment: @Chip -- note that a pointer to an array of `char *` is not a `char **` either, but a `char *(*)[]`. Yet, an array of `char *` does _decay_ to a pointer to its first element (not a pointer to the entire array), i.e. a `char **`, in most expressions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you had asked about converting an `int **` to an `int *`, the answer would be different. Let’s consider that first, because I suspect it is more representative of the question you intended to ask, and the `char *` case is more complicated because there is a special purpose involved in that.

Suppose you have several `int`: `int a, b, c, d;`. You can make an array of pointers to them: `int *p[] = { &a, &b, &c, &d };`. You can also make a pointer to one of these pointers: `int **q = &p[1];`. Now `q` points to `p[1]`, which contains the address of `b`.

When you write `*q`, the compiler knows `q` points to a pointer to an `int`, so it knows `*q` points to an `int`. If you write `**q`, the compiler, knowing that `*q` points to an `int`, will get `*q` from memory and use that as an address to get an `int`.

What happens if you convert `q` to an `int *` and try to use it, as in `printf("%d\n", * (int *) q);`? When you convert `q` to an `int *` you are (falsely) telling the compiler to treat it as a pointer to an `int`. Then, `* (int *) q` tells the compiler to go to that address and get an `int`.

This is invalid code—its behavior is not defined by the C standard. Specifically, it violates C 2018 6.5 7, which says that an object shall be accessed only by an lvalue expression that has a correct type—either a type compatible with that of the actual object or certain other cases, none of which apply here. At the place `q` points, there is a pointer to an `int`, but you tried to access it as if it were an `int`, and that is not allowed.

Now let’s consider the `char **` to `char *` case. As before, you might take some `char **q` and convert it to `char *`. Now, you are telling the compiler to go to the place `q` points, where there is a pointer to a `char`, and to access that memory location as if there were a `char` there.

C has special rules for this case. You **are** allowed to examine the bytes that make up objects by accessing them through a `char *`. So, if you convert a `char **` to `char *` and use it, as in `* (char *) q`, the result will be the first (lowest addressed) byte that makes up the pointer there. You can even look at the rest of the bytes, using code like this:

```
char *t = (char *) q;
printf("%d\n", t[0]);
printf("%d\n", t[1]);
printf("%d\n", t[2]);
printf("%d\n", t[3]);
```

This code will show you the decimal values for the first four bytes that make up the pointer to `char` that is at the location specified by `q`.

In summary, converting a `char **` to `char *` will allow you to examine the bytes that represent a `char *`. However, in general, you should not convert pointers of one indirection level to pointers of another indirection level.

Comment: Nice. Thank you!

Comment: Thank you so much! This makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 1):

I find pointers make much more sense when I think of them as memory addresses rather than some abstract high level thing.

So a char** is a memory address which points to, a memory address which points to, a character.

```
0x0020 -> 0x0010 -> 0x0041 'A'
```

When you cast you change the interpretation of the data, not the actual data. So the char* is

```
0x0020 -> 0x0010 (unprintable)
```

This is almost certainly not useful. Interpreting this random data as a null terminated string would be potentially disastrous.

Comment: Some casts change the data. For example, a cast from the `double` 3.5 to `int` changes the value from 3.5 to 3.